# Javascript event problem

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools

I am using joomla 1.5 i have MooTools files but while i am trying to submit form it shows error

`$(form.title).getValue()` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

`$(form.title)` this doesn't make any sense. Not sure what are you trying to do, but if you want to get the `title` attribute of the `form` element, the code for this would be `$('some-form-id').getProperty('title');`

`getValue()` is for getting a value of a single field element, not the form.